# Adding additional JPanels to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Rather basic question here guys.

Basically I have code like this:

```
public SuperPanel() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel1(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel2(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel3(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

And that all works well and good. The problem is that I have another part I wish to add to the center. Just using **`add(newPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER)`** doesn't work, obviously. But you can add `JPanel`s in `JPanel`s, correct?

So I made the following change:

```
public SuperPanel() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel1(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(supersweetpanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel3(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

With `supersweetpanel()` being:

```
public JPanel supersweetpanel() {
    JPanel sswp = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel2(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    return sswp;
}
```

Now it overrides `panel1`! If I set it to anything else (`CENTER`, `SOUTH`, what have you), the first two panels disappear entirely. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SuperPanel` is likely a subclass of `JPanel`, right? You are accidentally adding `panel2` to `this` (the `SuperPanel`), not `sswp`. Try:

```
public JPanel supersweetpanel() {
        JPanel sswp = new JPanel();
        sswp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        sswp.add(panel2(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return sswp;
    }
```

Comment: +1.  That's got to be it, and it gives a good example of why using inheritance can make things fragile.

Comment: Ah, that was it exactly. Lovely.

Comment: What Eddie said. It's a shame most Swing tutorials (and Swing GUIs) have such bad code.